# Size of Python Counter

Tags: python, counter

I want to know how many items are in a Python Counter, including the duplicates. I tried `len` and it tells me the number of unique items:

```
>>> c = Counter(x=3,y=7)
>>> len(c)
2
```

The best I have is `sum(c.itervalues())` which I suppose isn't terrible, but I was hoping the Counter object caches the value so I could access it in O(1).

Comment: Sorry, but your question "size of python Counter" and your further statements are confusing. Best would be to delete this question.
Size of the Counter is len and this has O (1) access.
Also in beginning of your try to describe what you want to know more deeply "I want to know how many items are in a Python Counter leads to the same answer: len (c). What you mean with "Best You have" further is the sum of all the values the counter holds and this is quite very different to your initial question and has nothing to do with it directly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Counter docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) give your `sum(c.itervalues())` answer as the standard pattern for this in the "Common patterns for working with Counter objects" section, so I doubt there's anything better.

As with the other `iter*` methods on dictionaries, in Python 3 `itervalues` is replaced by `values`.

Answer (score 7):

You can look through [the source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/38d47ac7fc2d/Lib/collections.py#l384); there is no cached value recording the number of items in the Counter. So the best you can do is `sum(c.itervalues())`.

```
In [108]: import collections

In [109]: c = collections.Counter(x=3, y=7)

In [110]: sum(c.itervalues())
Out[110]: 10
```

Comment: And for python3+ `sum(c.values()) `

Answer (score 1):

In python 3.10, `c.total()` can be simply used to obtain the result.

```
import collections
c = collections.Counter(x=3, y=7)
c.total()

# result: 10
```